# Issue with ErrorListPlot and PlotMarkers in Mathematica 11.2

Tags: plotting, bugs, marker

I think I found a bug in *Mathematica* 11.2 with `ErrorListPlot`. Any use of the option `PlotMarkers` in `ErrorListPlot` leads to no error bars, unless one uses `Joined -> True`. A similar (or the same) bug I saw reported for *Mathematica* 10. It seems it was corrected, but it has returned. I am running *Mathematica* on a Mac (macOSX).

Example:

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
data = Sort[Table[{{RandomReal[10], RandomReal[10]}, ErrorBar[RandomReal[5]]}, {i, 10}]];
ErrorListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All]
ErrorListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All, PlotMarkers -> "A"]
ErrorListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All, PlotMarkers -> "A", Joined -> True]
```

[image: Resulting plots]

The `PlotMarkers` that I want are more elaborate than an `"A"`, but this simple example illustrates the problem.

Any ideas on how I can avoid this issue? I want to specify `PlotMarkers` and I want the error bars, but I do not want the `Joined -> True` option.

Alternative packages to the `ErrorBarPlots` are also welcome.

Comment: In *Mathematica* 12.2 I do not reproduce this bug.

Comment: In Mathematica 12.1 I also no longer reproduce this bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems there is no alternative package to ErrorBarsPlot. I did a small package that implements error bars into ListPlot. It is also more "user friendly" considering the kind of plots that I need to do. On the other hand, it is less close to the ListPlot output than ErrorListPlot. This package is based on the function ELPlot defined below. This function solves the issue that I raised in the question above. The package I will post on a webpage soon. Any comments are welcome.

```
disk[color_, size_: 10, thickness_: 1] :=  Graphics[{color, AbsoluteThickness[thickness], Disk[]}, ImageSize -> size]

Options[ELPlot] = {
MarkersColor -> Black,
LinesColor -> Black,
MarkersSize -> 10,
MarkersThickness -> 1,
LinesThickness -> 1.2,
Markers -> disk,
LinesHorizontalLength -> 0.01
};

ELPlot[data_?ListQ, error_?ListQ, opts : OptionsPattern[{ELPlot, ListPlot}]] := 
Block[{dt = data, er = error, dataerrorpos, horizontallength, 
verticallines, horizontallines, 
mcolor = OptionValue[MarkersColor], 
lcolor = OptionValue[LinesColor], 
linesthickness = OptionValue[LinesThickness], 
markersthickness = OptionValue[MarkersThickness], 
markersize = OptionValue[MarkersSize], 
markers = OptionValue[Markers], 
k = OptionValue[LinesHorizontalLength], SavedOptionsLinTicks, 
SavedOptionsListPlot, LPopts},

If [Length[Dimensions[er]] == 1, er = Transpose[{er, er}]]; 

dataerrorpos = Flatten[{{dt[[#, 1]], dt[[#, 2]] + er[[#, 1]]}, {dt[[#, 1]], dt[[#, 2]] - er[[#, 2]]}} & /@ Range[Length[dt]], 1];
horizontallength = (Last[#] - First[#]) &[Sort[dt[[All, 1]]]];
horizontallines = Sequence @@ (Line[{{dataerrorpos[[#, 1]] - k horizontallength, dataerrorpos[[#, 2]]}, {dataerrorpos[[#, 1]] + k horizontallength, dataerrorpos[[#, 2]]}}] & /@ Range[Length[dataerrorpos]]);
verticallines = Sequence @@ (Line[{dataerrorpos[[#]], dataerrorpos[[# + 1]]}] & /@ Range[1, Length[dataerrorpos], 2]);
LPopts = FilterRules[{opts}, Options[ListPlot]];
Show[ListPlot[dt, LPopts, PlotMarkers -> {markers[mcolor, markersize, markersthickness] }], Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[linesthickness], lcolor, verticallines}], ListPlot[dt, LPopts, PlotMarkers -> markers[mcolor, markersize, markersthickness] }], Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[linesthickness], lcolor, horizontallines}]]
];
```

Here are screenshots:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Another workaround is simply to remove the line added due to `Joined -> True`:

```
ErrorListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All, PlotMarkers -> "A", Joined -> True] /. 
 Line[pts : {{x1_?NumericQ, _}, {x2_, _}, {_, _} ...}] /; x1 != x2 -> Nothing
```

> [image: plot]

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround use `Text` to replace the `Point`

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
data = Sort[
   Table[{{RandomReal[10], RandomReal[10]}, ErrorBar[RandomReal[5]]}, {i, 
     10}]];

ErrorListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All] /.
 Point[pts_List] :> (Text[Style["A", 14, Bold, Red], #] & /@ pts)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Indeed it solves the issue with the "A" or any text. On the other hand, if one wants to insert Graphics instead of Text, how should one adapt your workaround? I naively tried `ErrorListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All] /.  Point[pts_List] :> ( Graphics[Circle[#, 0.2]] & /@ pts)`

Comment: @DaviC.Rodrigues - [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) is not a `Graphics` primitive. Just use the `Circle[#, 0.2]` (`Graphics` primitive) without the `Graphics`.

Comment: Great, indeed it works, it is a nice workaround! It is a pity that we need to use a workaround...